# How can PCI-E 4x network card support 10GB/s speed?

Tags: networking, pci-express

This card https://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/smb_network_adapters_pci_card/en-9320tx-e/

Manufacturer claim this is 10GB/s card:

- 10 Gigabit throughput with 100-meter UTP cable
- PCI Express rev. 2.0 Specification x4 interface

Now wikipedia say, that 4x PCI-E slot revision 2 supports max 2.0 GB/s bandwidth. So how is this card supposed to work? Is the wikipedia wrong? Or manufacturer lying? Or is there some black magic I am not aware of?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express

[image: Edimax]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up gigabit and gigabytes.

2 gigabytes per second (GB/s) is 16 gigabits per second (Gb/s). Hence the PCIe x4 slot can easily support 10 gigabit with, in theory, 6Gb/s spare.

Answer (score 4):

They are in different units.

The network card is advertised in `Gigabits/s (Gb/s)`, whereas the PCI-E wikipedia page shows the speed in `Gigabytes/s (GB/s)`. 1 Gigabyte = 8 Gigabits or 1GB = 8Gb.

So the 4X PCI-E rev.2 actually supports 16Gb/s, which is more than enough to handle the 10GbE card.

(if you check the manufacturer's site, only Gb is used, not GB, as misquoted in the question)